How to interpret Bayes Factors from Bayesian Mann Whitney U Test?
I am comparing the cognitive performance of two different clinical groups. I used the DFBA R package to compute Bayesian Mann-Whitney Tests and am having difficulty interpreting the results. I know typically the MW test determines whether a group difference exists or not but I have also run frequentist stats that show evidence that group B may outperform group A which is what the results in favor of H0 seem to show in my results.

